# When i try to create a new file using nodejs i get an error

Tags: node.js, syntax-error

The video just said open cmd, type node and press enter then type touch script.js and it'll create a js file but I'm getting this, I'm using window.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> touch script.js
touch script.js
      ^^^^^^
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking help about.  What video? The `touch` command is a unix command used to fake the unix filesystem into thinking that the file `script.js` has changed.  It might help to see the contents of `script.js` or get a link to the video.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue ^^; For MAC user.

You are currently in your node interpreter you need to exit it and then run the Unix commands, touch script.js

To exit node

1. Press Ctrl+C twice or type .exit

To run Unix command

```
 2.Type touch script.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first create a file called  script.js.

-> for creating empty file

```
touch script.js
```

-> enter your node commands for eg

```
console.log("Hello world").
```

->then run `node script.js` .

If you rune node and type enter, you will enter into node's REPL mode where you can execute and try all the commands node offers [node REPL tutorial](http://3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-repl.php), [usage of node REPL mode](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-node-js-repl)

*NOTE:- when running node script.js make sure you are in the correct directory.otherwise you may get an error similar to "file not exist" as node would not be able to find your script.js if you are not in the right directory.*